# Troubleshooting Craftsman Garage Door Opener - Won't Close

Tags: garage-door-opener

Craftsman 41AC150-1M, 1/2 HP chain drive. Opens OK but when closing it will go some random distance then the light will go off for a split second and power to the chain drive will be cut. The door may coast about an inch at this point or maybe not. No retraction. After the flicker the light stays on. Then I have to wait a random amount of time before it will respond to the remote control again then the problem repeats.

When I press the remote control button the receiver light on the back flickers so it appears to be getting the signal.

The same problem happens using the button on the wall so it is not the remote control.

Both safety sensors have solid green lights all of the time. Blocking the beam causes the expected stop, retract and flashing of the light, so they are working.

Jiggling the wires into the back of the safety sensors does not change the lights - they remain solid green.

Jiggling the wires from the safety sensors into the back of the unit does not change the lights on the sensors - they remain solid green.

Disconnecting the door from the metal shuttle thingy does not solve the problem. The shuttle  randomly stops, so it is not a problem related to the door itself.

I plugged the unit into a different outlet and still have the problem so it's not the outlet.

The unit feels quite hot to the touch on the left side of the casing.

When the problem happens the receiver light on the back of the unit does not flash.

Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE - the chain was loose. I tightened it and now the problem is worse. When the opener stops the light goes off for at least a minute (before it was just a flicker). Changing the closing force doesn't help.

Comment: bridge/bypass the sensors

Comment: @Ruskes holding down the wall button to bypass the sensors gives the same result - keeps stopping when closing

Comment: OK, when it stops what happens next ? What is the tension on the chain, is it sloppy ?

Comment: @Ruskes it does the same thing - door stops, light flickers. Chain doesn't seem sloppy to me

Comment: To achieve proper chain tension, you must release the door from the opener before making any adjustments. When the chain is properly adjusted the chain will be 1/2" (for T-Rail) or 1/4 " (for Square Rail) above the base of the rail at its midpoint.

If the chain is either too loose or too tight, sprocket noise may result.

Comment: There have been a number of odd issues related to LED bulbs in garage door openers reported, so if it happens to have one, try removing that or changing to an old-fashioned bulb. My personal experience with whacky garage door opener behavior was a nearby lightning strike frying the control board, but that was clearly unsafe operation (it kept trying to drive the door through the floor) rather than stoppages.

Comment: @Ruskes the chain was loose - touching the t-rail. I tightened it and now the problem is worse. When it stops the light goes off for at least a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the circuit boards and reflowed the solder on the entire PSU board and the connectors and pots on the logic board. Now it works